# How do I avoid the text on my site is selectable?

Tags: 7

I am wondering how to avoid the text on a Drupal 6 site is selectable, ideally only for certain node types.

It should help to make life a bit harder for content thieves. Apparently there is a module in Wordpress that does exactly this, but I could not find such thing for Drupal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this code into your template.php file

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function <THEMENAME>_preprocess_page(&$vars){

    drupal_add_js("(function($){
        $.fn.disableSelection = function() {
            return this
                     .attr('unselectable', 'on')
                     .css('user-select', 'none')
                     .on('selectstart', false);
        };
    })(jQuery);", 'inline');
}
```

You can try css methods also

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

A JavaScript solution for IE is

```
onselectstart="return false;"
```

See [826782](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Comment: Sorry, could not figure out where exactly should I put  the code.

Comment: Just wondering, What if js is disabled ?

Comment: @j2r,  try adding the full content in `.jpg, .png, .gif `etc formats. `:)` Please let me know if you find other way.